# Unable to run aapt which has been installed through the Android SDK, what could be the reason?

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I'm trying to run a Gradle build within a Docker Ubuntu machine.

The application i'm compiling is supposed to generate an .apk file and so I'm using the aapt packager which comes as part of the Android SDK build-tools which I've installed using the following command:
`android update sdk -u -a -t 7` (Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3)

But then, when I run Gradle it fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Company-ServicesSDK:processReleaseResources'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/itai/repos/Company-Android_fork/.gradle/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt''
```

Through my Macbook I'm able to run the aapt and it works properly but from within the Docker machine, when I try to run it, I get:

```
bash: ./aapt: No such file or directory
```

Running `file aapt` from my Mac:

```
aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, not stripped
```

Anyone knows why it happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it interest anyone, I found that in order to fix this issue I had to install the following packages:

```
lib32z1
gcc-multilib
make
```

After installing these packages, running aapt gave me the proper output.